# Grails datepicker

Tags: grails

Using the grails datepicker control, is there a way to have it save time precision, but only show the user up to the day?  The user only cares about that day, but I need to add the time of day that entry was persisted into the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, datepicker doesnt save precision and sets some default values on the fields that are ommited.

If you need to persist the time of day entry was persisted, you can use `dateCreated` `lastUpdated` which will be automatically set when object will be persisted for the first time (`dateCreated`) or every time object will be modified (`lastUpdated`).

```
class Message {

    ...

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went down this route although I would prefer to orderBy only the one field instead of two.  It would be nice to hide the time fields and have the datepicker default the time values.

Comment: @Bill - you could alter time values in your controller also when your form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the attribute `precision='day'` to the tag, the time fields will not be shown, e.g.

```
<g:datePicker name="myDate" value="${new Date()}" precision="day"/>
```

You can set then the time fields in the controller to their default when the data is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to just store precision upto day in the database, you can get use the mapping. Assuming that your database is MSSQL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
class Message {

...

Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated

static mapping = {
    dateCreated sqlType:'date'
    lastUpated sqlType:'date'
}


}
```

Ref: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html

In your GSPs, you can use

```
<g:datePicker name="dateCreated" value="${new Date()}" precision="day" />
```

Ref: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/datePicker.html